# Prevent SCons from looking for standard tools

Tags: cross-compiling, scons

I am currently setting up SCons for cross-compilation with Windows as the host OS. I am building a custom `Environment` for the cross-compiler, but SCons insists on looking for Visual Studio each time I start it up (and prints a warning that it cannot find it, because I don't have it installed). Can I prevent it from looking for standard tools I know I am not going to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to do this, the first way is the easiest, try creating the environment specifying the compiler, as follows:

```python
env = Environment(CC = '/path/to/the/compiler')
```

You'll probably need to add paths for the linker and other tools as well. Then SCons shouldnt search for them.

Another way to do it would be to create a tool definition for the cross-compiler using the `tools` argument on the `Environment()` function as mentioned in the **CONFIGURATION FILE REFERENCE** section of the [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html), where the following is mentioned:

> Additionally, a specific set of tools with which to initialize the
>   environment may be specified as an optional keyword argument:
>
> `env = Environment(tools = ['msvc', 'lex'])`
>
> Non-built-in tools may be specified using the toolpath argument:
>
> `env = Environment(tools = ['default', 'foo'], toolpath = ['tools'])`
>
> ...
>
> The individual elements of the tools list may also themselves be
>   two-element lists of the form (toolname, kw_dict). SCons searches for
>   the toolname specification file as described above, and passes
>   kw_dict, which must be a dictionary, as keyword arguments to the
>   tool's generate function. The generate function can use the arguments
>   to modify the tool's behavior by setting up the environment in
>   different ways or otherwise changing its initialization.

*tools/my_tool.py:*

```python
def generate(env, **kw):
  # Sets MY_TOOL to the value of keyword argument 'arg1' or 1.
  env['MY_TOOL'] = kw.get('arg1', '1')
def exists(env):
  return 1
```

*SConstruct:*

```python
env = Environment(tools = ['default', ('my_tool', {'arg1': 'abc'})],
                  toolpath=['tools'])
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. I am going with the second approach, it seems more like what I need.

Comment: This solution did unfortunately not solve the problem of the warning. The problem here was that even though I create a custom environment, the `DefaultEnvironment` is still initialized with default tools. Adding a `DefaultEnvironment(tools=[])` fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

You may suppress warnings like this

```py
env.SetOption('warn', 'no-visual-c-missing')
```

For example, to cross-compile for ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers I'm doing this

```py
cross = 'arm-none-eabi-'
toolchain = {
    'CC': cross + 'gcc',
    'CXX': cross + 'g++',
    'AR': cross + 'ar',
    'AS': cross + 'gcc',
    'OBJCOPY': cross + 'objcopy',
    'SIZE': cross + 'size',
    'PROGSUFFIX': '.elf',
}

env = Environment(tools=('gcc', 'g++', 'gnulink', 'ar', 'as'), ENV=os.environ)
env.SetOption('warn', 'no-visual-c-missing')
env.Replace(**toolchain)
```

Comment: If you add DefaultEnvironment(tools=[]), then you  shouldn't need to suppress the warning assuming you also explicitly list the tools for each created Environment() and the lists don't include msvc,msvs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider redefining the [DefaultEnvironment](https://www.scons.org/doc/3.0.0/HTML/scons-user.html#idm139977756074448) instead of defining an `Environment`.

> All of the Builder functions that we've introduced so far, like
>   Program and Library, actually use a default construction environment
>   that contains settings for the various compilers and other tools that
>   SCons configures by default, or otherwise knows about and has
>   discovered on your system. The goal of the default construction
>   environment is to make many configurations to "just work" to build
>   software using readily available tools with a minimum of configuration
>   changes.

This way, *SCons* won't try to make predictions based on common usage and apply them to your project. For example:

```
PATH = {'PATH' : ['C:/cygwin/bin']}
env = Environment(ENV=PATH)
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

will make assumptions based on what it thinks is the most likely case & try to find *Visual Studio* before resorting to whatever it finds in PATH, whereas:

```
PATH = {'PATH' : ['C:/cygwin/bin']}
env = DefaultEnvironment(ENV=PATH)
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

will make no such a assumption, and go directly to whatever it finds in PATH without looking for *Visual Studio*.