# Is there any way to add arm compiler to Scons Toolchain?

Tags: scons

I tried by adding it using :

```
--tc=gcc and also using --target=arm
```

it looks like scons do not support it.
Im not using sbuild Im using parts and Im looking for way to to compile my program with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc when running scons --tc=gcc --target=arm currently I get an error that it cannot find gcc on target posix-arm
is there any way to change the default compiler of scons if the compiler is not included in scons Tools directory using parts?

Thank you

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112641/cross-compiling-swiften-library-for-arm-embedded-with-scons-makery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205210/prevent-scons-from-looking-for-standard-tools . It's still a bit unclear what your actual question is. You may want to edit it and, for example, clarify whether you have actually build a Tool already (how does the code for it look like?) or what it is that you're struggling with. At the moment I can only answer, "Yes, there are ways." but they depend on what you want to do...;)

Comment: Also: Where did you download SBuild from? As far as I know it's not an open-source project, yet.

Comment: Looks like sbuild is fairly old. I can't tell if it's been updated. I see one listing where it looks like their embedding scons 0.96.1 (which is ancient).  You'll really be best off asking the sbuild folks. There's an email link on the site.

Comment: Likely the support you are looking for would need to be added to the sbuild framework. At least from reading the docs for sbuild it looks like they've wrapped scons and added another layer which includes they're mechanism for specifying compiler toolchains and cross compiles.

Comment: Im not using sbuild Im using parts and Im looking for way to to compile my program with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc when running scons --tc=gcc --target=arm