# How do I cross-compile scons (with gcc) on Windows with Visual Studio installed?

Tags: gcc, g++, scons

I have an existing makefile project that I am migrating to `scons`.

The makefile builds several Windows executables with `gcc` and `g++`.

However, I also have Visual Studio installed for C# development.

It appears that `scons` is trying to use the Visual Studio tools rather than the gcc ones:

```
cl /Fofoo\bar.o /c foo\bar.c /nologo -g -mno-ms-bitfields -fshort-enums -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs /D-DUNIT_TESTS /I. <more includes follow...>
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-g'
```

I have read several answers and have tried adding:

```
env["CC"] = "gcc"
env["CXX"] = "g++"
env["LINK"] = "g++"
```

in my `Sconstruct` file. This has the effect of correctly changing the *tool*, but not the command syntax:

```
gcc /Fofoo\bar.o /c foo\bar.c /nologo -g -mno-ms-bitfields -fshort-enums -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs /D-DUNIT_TESTS /I. <more includes follow...>
gcc: error: /Fofoo\bar.o: No such file or directory
```

How can I ensure that scons uses my desired tools and also uses the correct syntax for the command line options (e.g. `-I` instead of `/I`)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205210/prevent-scons-from-looking-for-standard-tools

Comment: Please post a simple SConstruct which demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have to guess the issue your SConstruct is something like this:

```
env=Environment()
env["CC"] = "gcc"
env["CXX"] = "g++"
env["LINK"] = "g++"
env['CCFLAGS']='-mno-ms-bitfields -fshort-enums -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs'
env['CPPDEFINES']=['-DUNIT_TESTS']
env['CPPPATH'] = ['.']
```

Given that the default list of tools to configure on Windows is the following in order and it will stop configuring tools once it finds one of these and then it sets up the flags which should work for such tools.

```
c_compilers = ['msvc', 'mingw', 'gcc', 'intelc', 'icl', 'icc', 'cc', 'bcc32']
```

You'll need to explicitly list the tools you want initialized (And not allow SCons to add the default tools) and the PATH they will be found in.  Also your CPPDEFINES should be ['UNIT_TESTS'] and not ['-DUNIT_TESTS'] SCons will add the appropriate flags.  Note you may need to add other tools if you are using them in your build.

```
env=Environment(tools=[])
env.AppendENVPath('PATH', PATH_TO_YOUR_COMPILERS)
for tool in ['gcc','gnulink','ar']:
   env.Tool(tool)
env['CCFLAGS']='-mno-ms-bitfields -fshort-enums -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs'
env['CPPDEFINES']=['UNIT_TESTS']
env['CPPPATH'] = ['.']
```